# How to change the behaviour of std::filesystem::temp_directory_path() returning a path with 8.3 alias in Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, std-filesystem

Using [`temp_directory_path()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/temp_directory_path) of [`std::experimental::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) in Visual Studio 2015:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
int main() {
    std::cout << fs::temp_directory_path().generic_string() << std::endl;
    std::cout << fs::temp_directory_path() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\
```

Is it possible get the full path name `C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Temp/` instead of the [8.3 alias](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#short_vs._long_names)?

Using Visual C++, `fs::temp_directory_path()` calls e.g. `_Temp_get(wchar_t (&)[_MAX_FILESYS_NAME])` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\filesystem`. However the source of that function does not seem to be available.

Comment: You might look at GetLongPathName. Not sure if it meets your needs or not.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: You cannot *make* that function return anything other than what the implementation returns. You could perhaps write a new function or use Windows API functions to do an equivalent thing.